# Data extension export problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data

I want to export records from a data extension but when I am exporting the records into csv file I found out that most of the records contain unusual name like this -> Raï¿½l Rodrï¿½guez Ramï¿½rez. so after checking the data extension I find that there is ? between the records like this->ROXANA SALDA�A V�ZQUEZ
can anyone tell why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem with exporting, it seems like a problem with how you open the file. Do you just double-clik on it and open in Excel?

If so, try the following:

1. Open a blank sheet in Excel
2. Click on the "Data" tab
3. Choose "From Text/CSV"
4. Choose the file you downloaded from SFMC
5. From the "File Origin" dropdown choose "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)"
6. Click on Load/follow the wizard

Comment: Thanks for this info.

Comment: If it helped, please remember to upvote and accept!